# Volume label syntax is incorrect using maven-dotnet-plugin

Tags: .net, maven, jenkins, hudson, maven-3

Using the maven-dotnet-plugin I am getting the error shown at the end of this post.

The Jenkins workspace is set at C:\Jenkins

Does anyone know where or how to change the format of the pathnames for use in the dotnet plugin, or another way to get this to work?

The error I am getting is shown in detail below.

```
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Jenkins\ExternalFrame\au.com.bushlife.dotnet.revit:builder\builds\2012-09-20_17-10-03\log (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuild$ProxyImpl2.<init>(MavenBuild.java:472)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:682)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1502)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:477)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
FATAL: Failed to create a temporary file in C:\Jenkins\ExternalFrame\au.com.bushlife.dotnet.revit:builder\builds\2012-09-20_17-10-03
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to create a temporary file in C:\Jenkins\ExternalFrame\au.com.bushlife.dotnet.revit:builder\builds\2012-09-20_17-10-03
    at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:67)
    at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:54)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:174)
    at hudson.model.Run.save(Run.java:1638)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:991)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:639)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1527)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:477)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:65)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path being constructed is an invalid path due to the colons being placed in the path string.  This is a plugin bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a permission issue to your file system.
Take a look at this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jenkinsci-users/9nux4H8YWe8

Comment: It appears to be a bug in the maven dot net plugin.  The path it is trying to use contains : character which is non-acceptable path.